# How to implement a Tracking Pixel that counts the Page Views?

Tags: javascript, spring, grails, tracking

I want to implement a tracking pixel in my pages and email like this:

```
<img src="someurl/tracking.js">
```

What do I have to write in my tracking.js in order to get the code executed? Can I use JQuery inside this code?

Comment: It's just an image. You can count page views and set and count cookies from your server.

Comment: You shouldn't load a js script. If you want to add properties, it usually done like `<img src="someurl/tracking.gif?prop1=value"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in this blog post: http://grooovygeorge.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/serving-a-blind-gif-from-a-string-in-grails/

```
 import org.springframework.security.core.codec.Base64

class TrackingController {


private static final String PIXEL_B64 = "R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
private static final byte[] PIXEL_BYTES = Base64.decode(PIXEL_B64.getBytes())


def track() {

 // track the request here...
 // send the GIF image
 response.setContentType("image/gif")
 response.outputStream << PIXEL_BYTES
 return // this statement is required.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [src](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp) attribute of the `img` tag can be either absolute image URL or relative image URL. You cannot just run arbitrary JavaScript that way. Use instead

```
<script src="someurl/tracking.js"/>
```

Comment: What do I have to do in my tracking.js file?

Comment: Put on the same server as the main HTML document.

Comment: can I use JQuery inside? How do I get the JavaScript executed?